# Single Sign On WinForms apps and asp.net wep app

Tags: asp.net, winforms, authentication, single-sign-on, wif

I've been assigned to find a way of implementing SSO in our products. We have several Winform applications and one asp.net 4.0 web app (not MVC).

All the products are built using .Net 4.0, the web app is ASP.NET 4.0.
Some of the Winforms are commmunicating with our API via web services (asmx) and some uses our API directly. The web app is using the same API as well. We offer a set of web services (asmx) that uses the same API to external clients.

Currently we have our own authentication implementation (user, password, roles) in our systems and we would like to replace that with SSO. Or can these two authentication regimes co-exist somehow? The Winforms are used in intranets and the web app is used both in intranets and we also hosts the web apps for clients (accesible from the Internet).

The users are created in our system, but at the same time we import users from Active Directory using our own tool. Active Directory is really the primary user source.

I have read about Windows Identity Foundation and I wonder if I can use that to implement SSO. But what I don't understand is how to use WIF in the winform applications when they use the API directly.

What I would like to achieve is to remove all user administration from our system and use Active Directory as the user source. I guess that means using ADFS 2.0 to create claims, etc.

I can use .Net Framework 4.5 in this implementation (I know that WIF is now a first class citizen in .Net Framework 4.5).

Do you have any advices how to do this? Is WIF the best alternative to achieve SSO across winforms applications and web apps?

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to get the WIF authentication cookie from within the WinForms application.

To do it, you just host the `WebBrowser` control and point it to the login page of your web application. Assuming the web application is federated with the ADFS2, the web browser control will automatically follow the flow - it will redirect to ADFS and stop there to show the prompt for user credentials (ADFS2 in Forms Authentication mode) or just authenticate using NTLM/Kerberos (ADFS2 in Windows authentication mode). Then the web browser will redirect back to your application.

This is where you hook your code. You just add a handler to the web browser's navigation event and you check when it comes back to your application AFTER ADFS2.0 authenticates the user. You can then call the `InternetGetCookie` method in the WinForms app to get all the authentication cookies issued by your application and you can close the window which hosts the web browser.

At this point, you have all authentication cookies issued by WIF (the `SessionAuthenticationModule`) for your application. You can now call your application web services and inject cookies into http calls. The web server will correctly recognize users as authenticated which means that all you have to do is to add proper authorization to your web services (the `PrincipalPermission` on your web methods should do).

An alternative approach would be to expose WCF services from your web application and guard them with WS-Federation active authentication. The downside of this approach is (in my opinion) that if your identity provider (ADFS) is further federated with yet another identity provider which DOES NOT necessarily implement WS-Trust/WS-Federation then the active authentication will probably fail (because the other identity provider does not implement it) while the passive scenario will still work (a bunch of redirects will sooner ot later end with a page which requires user to provide the credentials but the flow of authentication protocols between consecutive identity providers does not matter).

Comment: Very thorough answer, Wiktor:) So there is no way of using WIF in Winforms without the WebBrowser control? The best way would perhaps be to refactor all Winform applications to use WCF services and let WIF do it's work from there?

Comment: I am not sure if active scenario (WIF over WCF) is better. Suppose the ADFS is federated with yet another custom STS which is then federated with Google over Oauth2. The passive scenario will handle this easily (it is just a matter of few redirects) but the active scenario will fail. In our system we have decided to go with the passive scenario, we host web browser in our win forms applications, we catch local auth cookie and feed the web service proxy with the cookie so that the server recognizes the win forms application as authenticated. It works for like 2 years now, with no major issues.